# Problem wind Pandas map method (for adding columns in dataframe from another dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, series

I have a datafram with a 'Country' column and some other data and I want to add longitude and latitude for each country from another dataframe . I use a "map" method for finding eache country in the 2nd dataframe and adding to the first one.

```
df_filteres['longitude'] = df_filteres['Country'].map(lambda item : df_countries[df_countries['country'] == item].iloc[0, 2])
```

it works if I replace 'item' with an example country name (ex.Germany) , but with 'item' it returns this error :

**IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds**

which part is incorrect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
df_filteres['longitude'] = df_filteres['Country'].map(df_countries.set_index('country').iloc[:, 1])
```

Comment: `.map` is a good tool to use, so long as you use it tactfully.  ;-)

Comment: yep! but I couldn't understand the usage of a function in the map, I defined a function that finds a related value in another Dataframe ( I mean by the name of the country ), because I thought the map calls this function for each row. I tried with both 'lambda' and 'def' , but none of them worked.why?

Comment: @user9275707  [`.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) accepts function, collections or Series.  You can use a Series like I do here (since `iloc[:, 1]` returns a column which is a kind of Pandas Series).   Then, since we set `country` as index, we can use the value of country in one df to index with the country df to get its value (with matching index).  This is how the logics above work.

Comment: @user9275707  Your codes with lambda function specified `iloc[0, 2]` but when there is no match, getting the `iloc[0]` will throw an error since there is no row with relative index 0 to index for.  With my codes, if there is no match, it will just return `NaN`.   Hope this make clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to solve this problem without using map. Read through the [join / merge / concatenate documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) to better understand the style of operation you are performing, and find the appropriate example to work from.

Generally for this problem you would do a left merge on the key `country` but only with the column `longitude` belonging to the other dataframe.

```py
df_subset = df_countries[['country', 'longitude']]
df_filteres = df_filteres.merge(df_subset, on='country', how='left')
```

Comment: thank you, you're right. 'map' was bad idea, it is much easier with merge.